# Laravel Relationship Pivot table multiple relations

Tags: laravel, model, relation

Hi need to somehow get relation between these Models

1) AutoService Model

2) Master Model

3) Service Model

here is my pivot table structure

```
id, auto_service_id, master_id, service_id
```

Now I need to get For every AutoService its Masters and The Services they provide.

One Master can belong to many AutoServices and provide different Services  in each of them.

The same service may be provided by Multiple masters in the same AutoService.

How to build relations between these models?

Answer (score 0):

You should have one pivot table `autoservice_service`.

In your Service Models

```
public function autoServices(){
  $this->belongsToMany('App\AutoService');
}
```

In your Master model

```
public function autoServices(){
  $this->hasMany('App\AutoService');
}
```

In your AutoService model

```
public function services(){
  $this->belongsToMany('App\Service');
}
public function masters(){
  $this->belongsTo('App\Master');
}
```

in pivot tables use then `service_id`, `master_id`, `autoservice_id`. If you want to use timestamps use method `withTimestamps()` (f.e. `$this->belongsToMany('App\Master')->withTimestamps();`

EDIT: 
If you want to make a relationship between Master and Service in which one Master can have multiple services and vice versa, you should make another pivot table `master_service`. In `Service` model:

```
public function masters(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Master');
}
```

and in `Master` model:

```
public function services(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Service');
}
```

now you're able to check what master does, examples

```
1) Services of master
App\Master::find($id)->services();
2) Which masters do service
App\Service::find($id)->masters();
```

The other workaround is that you can add another foreign key in your pivot table, and then use `->withPivot('column1', 'column2')`.

Comment: but the same service may be provided by multiple masters. what to do in this situation? and where is the relation between master and service. how to get which master does what?

Comment: I know but it should depend on AutoService either, because the same Master can provide different Services in differen AutoServices. So it should be 1-N-N

Comment: Check if this helps you now :) added 1-N relationship for Master - Autoservice